# Change price when selected option has no value

Tags: jquery, magento

So my code is almost ready but I have one little problem. I have a product with different options you can choose. Depending on the chosen option the price is changing. At first it didn't work because the option with the text "Choose option.." had no price attribute. I changed this:

```
jQuery('select').one('change', function()
{
    jQuery(this).find('option').first().attr("price", "0");
});
```

In my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ojv77sz9/1/ everythings works really fine but when I use this on the website it doesnt work. I get an error message when I chose a configuration and change it back to "Choose option.." All it says is

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=]
>       at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (:15:61)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

It seems to have a conflict with the `jquery.min.js`. So, I was thinking if there is another way to program the code. Hope you have any advise.

Comment: can we see that problem on your live product ? any link?

Comment: Its on not one `jQuery('select').on('change', function(){`

Comment: Sorry no live link available at the moment ... thanks for the "one" hint but it still wont work :(

Comment: can you please check version of jquery in fiddle & your code are same?